# Empty Trunk Character caused Connection Close and Chrome logged CORS error in browser

Tags: angular, fiddler, asp.net-core-2.2, abp

Our front-end is Angular and Backend is .Net Core 2.2. I experienced intermittent CORS error (or might be some other issue) when calling from front-end to backend.

When we call backend API in Chrome, Chrome sometimes throws error in the console "...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", causing webpag not loading. When error happens, there is no response content and no response header. And the issue could happen when I disable cache (with header or chrome's devtool) and disable CORS (with Chrome Extension).

I guess browser is not able to parse the response body, So I used fiddler to track the response:

Initially I only got Empty Trunk "30 0D 0A 0D 0A" and Fiddler received 500 error. At the same time, Chrome throws CROS error and webpage doesn't load.

[image: Response size is 0]

[image: Initial Error Header - Closed Connection]

[image: Illegal Empty Trunk Body 30 0D 0A 0D 0A]

And if I wait for 30 seconds to 1 minute, the Fiddler record changed from 500 (failure) to 200 (successful):

[image: Chunked Transfer-Encoding]

[image: Good Headers]

[image: Good Sample Body]

It made me think it might be an issue with chunked Transfer-Encoding (as shown in the third picture), so I tried to disable chunked encoding via assigning Response header the ContentLength. But issue still persists.

Kind of desperate on this error. Any insight/suggestion would be really appreciated!

Comment: So there is a lot of information here and it feels a little jumbled.  Also, a lot of the things you are describing seem very unlikely.  First, you describe an intermittent CORS error but it is very unlikely that CORS would be intermittent.  It is also extremely unlikely for some other error to mask itself as CORS.  Maybe start by trying to isolate the conditions that cause the CORS error.  When you get a CORS error is the origin header the same as the host (keep in mind that localhost and the hostname of your computer will be treated as two different hosts).

Comment: @Pace Thank you for your response! Yeah, another more unlikely thing is that if I was able to load the page and I kept hitting F5 to refresh, the CORS issue doesn't happen. And if I use Ctrl+F5, then the CORS issue happens intermittently. I tried to disable/uncheck "Automatic Detect Configuration" in LAN Settings in IE, the successful loading rate became higher, but the loading still sometimes failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right. Seems root cause "detected" -- Our company synchronizes user folders to virtual drive automatically, like Pictures/Documents/Temp Folders are all synced to virtual drive. That function ensures no data loss and easier workstation replacement, but we're experiencing a lot of delay when trying to do copy/paste or open any user folder. So once I went to airplane mode or only hit F5 rather than Ctrl+F5, I don't experience the intermittent CORS issue any more. I guess Chrome thinks it's CORS issue perhaps because the response is injected by this 'proxy' layer.

If anyone has done following things:

1. Followed exactly correct CORS setup at server side. And CORS
   logging are all successful. For example: Preflight returns 204; WebDavModule has been disabled so that PUT and DELETE are not prevented; Origin is included in the list of CORS origin list; There is 'Vary: Origin' Response Header.
2. Tried to disable Chunked Transfer Encoding for Server Responses by setting correct response length in the header.
3. Tried to disable cache or set up Cache-Control to be 'no-cache' in the response header.
4. Fiddler's response is able to change from 500 to 200 and receive full response after some waiting period.
5. Unchecked the automatic detect configuration in "LAN Setting" in Connections tab (Internet Configuration).
6. Set hostingmode to be 'Inprocess' in web.config.

Please check if your company has similar synchronization set up...